# マルコフ連鎖を使った文章自動生成プログラムを動かしたらシンタックスエラーが出ました。

Tags: python3

https://github.com/karaage0703/TextGenerator を参考にし、PrepareChain.pyを起動させたところ次のようなエラーが出ました。

```
C:\Users\Desktop>python PrepareChain.py sample.txt
  File "PrepareChain.py", line 72
    text = re.sub(ur"({0})".format(delimiter), r"\1\n", text)
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

環境は
python3.6.5
windows10
です。72行目に修正箇所があるということなのでしょうか。

以下PrepareChain.pyの中身です。

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

u"""
マルコフ連鎖を用いて適当な文章を自動生成するファイル
"""

import os.path
import sqlite3
import random
import sys

from PrepareChain import PrepareChain

numb_sentence = 5

class GenerateText(object):
    u"""
    文章生成用クラス
    """

    # def __init__(self, n=10):
    def __init__(self):
        # print ("sentence_numb=" + str(numb_sentence))
        u"""
        初期化メソッド
        @param n いくつの文章を生成するか
        """
        self.n = numb_sentence

    def generate(self):
        u"""
        実際に生成する
        @return 生成された文章
        """
        # DBが存在しないときは例外をあげる
        if not os.path.exists(PrepareChain.DB_PATH):
            raise IOError(u"DBファイルが存在しません")

        # DBオープン
        con = sqlite3.connect(PrepareChain.DB_PATH)
        con.row_factory = sqlite3.Row

        # 最終的にできる文章
        generated_text = u""

        # 指定の数だけ作成する
        for i in xrange(self.n):
            text = self._generate_sentence(con)
            generated_text += text

        # DBクローズ
        con.close()

        return generated_text

    def _generate_sentence(self, con):
        u"""
        ランダムに一文を生成する
        @param con DBコネクション
        @return 生成された1つの文章
        """
        # 生成文章のリスト
        morphemes = []

        # はじまりを取得
        first_triplet = self._get_first_triplet(con)
        morphemes.append(first_triplet[1])
        morphemes.append(first_triplet[2])

        # 文章を紡いでいく
        while morphemes[-1] != PrepareChain.END:
            prefix1 = morphemes[-2]
            prefix2 = morphemes[-1]
            triplet = self._get_triplet(con, prefix1, prefix2)
            morphemes.append(triplet[2])

        # 連結
        result = "".join(morphemes[:-1])

        return result

    def _get_chain_from_DB(self, con, prefixes):
        u"""
        チェーンの情報をDBから取得する
        @param con DBコネクション
        @param prefixes チェーンを取得するprefixの条件 tupleかlist
        @return チェーンの情報の配列
        """
        # ベースとなるSQL
        sql = u"select prefix1, prefix2, suffix, freq from chain_freqs where prefix1 = ?"

        # prefixが2つなら条件に加える
        if len(prefixes) == 2:
            sql += u" and prefix2 = ?"

        # 結果
        result = []

        # DBから取得
        cursor = con.execute(sql, prefixes)
        for row in cursor:
            result.append(dict(row))

        return result

    def _get_first_triplet(self, con):
        u"""
        文章のはじまりの3つ組をランダムに取得する
        @param con DBコネクション
        @return 文章のはじまりの3つ組のタプル
        """
        # BEGINをprefix1としてチェーンを取得
        prefixes = (PrepareChain.BEGIN,)

        # チェーン情報を取得
        chains = self._get_chain_from_DB(con, prefixes)

        # 取得したチェーンから、確率的に1つ選ぶ
        triplet = self._get_probable_triplet(chains)

        return (triplet["prefix1"], triplet["prefix2"], triplet["suffix"])

    def _get_triplet(self, con, prefix1, prefix2):
        u"""
        prefix1とprefix2からsuffixをランダムに取得する
        @param con DBコネクション
        @param prefix1 1つ目のprefix
        @param prefix2 2つ目のprefix
        @return 3つ組のタプル
        """
        # BEGINをprefix1としてチェーンを取得
        prefixes = (prefix1, prefix2)

        # チェーン情報を取得
        chains = self._get_chain_from_DB(con, prefixes)

        # 取得したチェーンから、確率的に1つ選ぶ
        triplet = self._get_probable_triplet(chains)

        return (triplet["prefix1"], triplet["prefix2"], triplet["suffix"])

    def _get_probable_triplet(self, chains):
        u"""
        チェーンの配列の中から確率的に1つを返す
        @param chains チェーンの配列
        @return 確率的に選んだ3つ組
        """
        # 確率配列
        probability = []

        # 確率に合うように、インデックスを入れる
        for (index, chain) in enumerate(chains):
            for j in xrange(chain["freq"]):
                probability.append(index)

        # ランダムに1つを選ぶ
        chain_index = random.choice(probability)

        return chains[chain_index]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    param = sys.argv
    if (len(param) != 2):
        print ("Usage: $ python " + param[0] + " number")
        quit()  

    numb_sentence = int(param[1])

    generator = GenerateText()
    gen_txt = generator.generate()
    print (gen_txt.encode('utf_8'))
```

Comment: 質問で提示されているのは、`PrepareChain.py`ではなくリンク先の`GenerateText.py`に当たる内容に見えます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python3 では `r"string"` は正規表現を表し、 `u"string"` 形式はPython2との互換性のために利用可能ですが、 `ur"string"` は`Invalid Syntax`になるというバグがあります。
[Issue 15096: Drop support for the "ur" string prefix - Python tracker](https://bugs.python.org/issue15096)

このため、代わりに `r"string"` 形式に書き換えて実行してください。

Comment: ソース内のu"...."をすべてr"...."に書き換えてみたところ 　                              
`C:\Users\Desktop>python PrepareChain.py sample.txt
  File "PrepareChain.py", line 72
    text = re.sub(ur"({0})".format(delimiter), r"\1\n", text)
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`                                                                                                             
と同じエラーが出ました。r"string"形式への書き換え方が間違っているのでしょうか。

Comment: そのコメント内で、 `ur"({0})".format(delimiter)` というのが残っているように見えるのですが……

Comment: すいませんポカしてました。直したところ今度は  `C:\Users\Desktop>python PrepareChain.py sample.txt
  File "PrepareChain.py", line 158
    print "|".join(triplet), "\t", triplet_freqs[triplet]` とでるようになりました。

Comment: 今回の `syntax error` は解決したのでしょうか。別の問題のようですので、別の質問に分けたほうがよろしいかと存じます。

Comment: これも’syntax error’でしたが見直したらちょっとしたタイプミスでしたので問題解決しました。ここまで付き合っていただきありがとうございました。

Comment: 解決したようでなによりです。✔ボタン（解決としてマーク）を押して、この質問を解決したものとして終了させてください。